# Two JXTables with same custom model - How to make cells editable in one table but non-editable in the second?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, tablemodel, jxtable

I have a custom table model whose data I want to edit in one JXTable, but view-only in a second JXTable. Can this be done without having two separate models?
Is there some way of overriding model.isCellEditable for the view-only table?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.decorator.ColorHighlighter;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.decorator.ComponentAdapter;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.decorator.HighlightPredicate;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel {

  private JSplitPane splitPane;
  private JXTable viewTable, editTable;

  private class CustomModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    public static final int SPORT_COL = 0;
    public static final int EQUIPMENT_COL = 1;
    private final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
      "Sport",
      "Equipment"
    };
    private Map<String, String> sports;
    private List<String> set;

    public CustomModel() {
      sports = new TreeMap<String, String>();
      sports.put("Rugby", "Headguard");
      sports.put("Hurling", "Sliotar");
      sports.put("Tennis", "Racket");
      set = new ArrayList<String>(sports.keySet());
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
      return sports.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
      return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
      return COLUMN_NAMES[columnIndex];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
      String sport = set.get(rowIndex);
      switch (columnIndex) {
        case SPORT_COL:
          return sport;
        case EQUIPMENT_COL:
          return sports.get(sport);
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
      if (columnIndex == EQUIPMENT_COL) {
        if (aValue != null) {
          String sport = (String) getValueAt(rowIndex, SPORT_COL);
          String equip = (String) aValue;
          sports.put(sport, equip);
          fireTableDataChanged();
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
      return columnIndex == EQUIPMENT_COL;
    }
  }
  private CustomModel model;

  public SSCCE() {
    super();

    model = new CustomModel();
    viewTable = new JXTable(model);
    editTable = new JXTable(model);
    editTable.addHighlighter(new ColorHighlighter(new HighlightPredicate() {
      @Override
      public boolean isHighlighted(Component renderer, ComponentAdapter adapter) {
        return adapter.isEditable();
      }
    }, Color.GREEN.brighter(), Color.BLACK));

    JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 10));
    panelLeft.add(new JLabel("Editable"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panelLeft.add(new JScrollPane(editTable));
    JPanel panelRight = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 10));
    panelRight.add(new JLabel("How to make non-editable?"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panelRight.add(new JScrollPane(viewTable));

    splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, panelLeft, panelRight);
    add(splitPane);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("One Model | Two Views");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new SSCCE(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(360, 240);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SwingX supports configuring the editability on the view layer. No need to touch your model, keep it editable as appropriate:

```
viewTable = new JXTable(model);
viewTable.setEditable(false);
editTable = new JXTable(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `WrapperTableModel` which delegates all the calls to the inner `TableModel` but returns false from `isCellEditable().`

Set the first editable model to the table1 and the wrapper model (holding reference to the first) in the table2.

Comment: @StanislavL Thanks, but accepted answer is more concise for JXTable